# css webapp window resize causing div to become too large for window

Tags: css, html, window

See link for code...

using this code, the page gives me the proper width, on resizing also.
But the height has to be regulated with jQuery. This gives me a div where the height is a little more that the 100% i want, and does not change when resizing the page's height...

`Here is the code:` http://jsfiddle.net/T6Uv4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what you are trying to do. but if you change `position: absolute;` to `position: fixed;` it should resize as the page does.

But if you are having a scroll on the page then you might not want it to stay in the same location on the page.

The problem with `position: absolute;` its not dynamic so if you change the browser size it stays its original size as when the page first loaded. if you CRTL+F5 the page after changing the browser the content will pop into the place it should be for `position: absolute;`

Here is a `position: relative;` [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FDZnG/1/)

Here is your jquery code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    $('#content').css({'height':windowHeight+'px'});
});
</script>
```

Is this more what you were looking for?

New jsfiddle update: [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T6Uv4/1/)

You needed to remove the body padding and margin and also the border around the container.

Comment: You will need to show us the full code that you are trying to use. go to jsfiddle and place your code there so we can have a play around with it.

Comment: ok, but what is intresting is this: changing it to: `#content {
  border: 2px solid;
    position: relative;
  }`

Comment: gives me the perfect position, perfect width but the height is a little too large

Comment: So is `position: relative;` now working for you. I know it would be due to the position. if the height is to long you can give it a `min-height` value

Comment: well, i now see that the div's width is good, but the height is only 10px or so, why is this not 100% just like the width?

Comment: If its `position:relative` then the height will be the same height as the last bit of text. if you want it to be the full height of the page you can use a little bit of jQuery to force a new height onto `content`

Comment: is this more what you are looking for: [fiddle height](http://jsfiddle.net/FDZnG/1/)

Comment: looks good in the fiddle, but when i add it as a script above my div it does not work... :(

Comment: have you loaded jquery onto the page?

Comment: i got it working, the div auto corrects it's height, but it stays at 300px or so

Comment: oh, when loading the page, it makes the div 100px larger than the window each time you refresh

Comment: is it not supposed to automatically resize when resizing the window?

Comment: Its hard for me to help without seeing your full code. do you have the page online somewhere? you could always try `body{overflow:hidden;}`

Comment: So what is the next problem that you are having?

Comment: mmh, strange.. the content div still initially sets it's height a little too large and does not resize when resizing the browser window.

Comment: ok, i changed some css and now it works, but is it supposed to resize when resizing the browser window just like the width does?

Comment: Here is the same but with `position:fixed` [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T6Uv4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I try to explain this behaviour:

If you have a screen 1000px resolution (only an example), the 80% is 800px. But if you resize the page to 500px wide, the 80% caught 400px. Those 400px + 210px margin= 610px (not 500px!)

**Solution:** try put the left `margin` and your `padding` in porcentual values or in em units, to make the margin resizes within the content.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wMDQt/).

Note that when you resize so much the screen, the scrollbar appears again. You can fix it changing the border to *em* units. Perfect solution came across setting no fixed values in whole page.

For more complex size-adjust you could use [Mediaqueries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Comment: no, this does not respect the margin (overlap), the width is good but the height is a little too large